# Kivy: How display FilechooserListView with current content

Tags: kivy

I select the file in FileChooserListView and I remove it by using the next sequence commands:

```
self.fichoo = FileChooserListView()
. . .
. . .
os.remove(self.fichoo.selection[0])
del self.fichoo.selection[0]
```

After removing the file is physically removed from disc, but it will remain displayed in FileChooserListView.

How can I remove file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refresh the content of your `Filechooser` to show the change. The only way I know (in addition to select another directory) is using [`_update_files`](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/8776f284f75f5589d3b0c6f1e82795d73e9f3c45/kivy/uix/filechooser.py#L680) method.

A complete example:

```
import os
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileChooserListView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<WarningPopup@Popup>:
    title: 'Warning'
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 200

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: 'Do you really want to delete this element?'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.3
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.dismiss()
            Button:
                text: "Accept"
                on_release:
                    root.parent_inst.delete()
                    root.dismiss()
''')


class WarningPopup(Popup):
    def __init__(self, parent_inst, *args,  **kwargs):
        super(WarningPopup, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parent_inst = parent_inst


class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.fichoo = FileChooserListView()
        self.popup = WarningPopup(self)
        btn_delete = Button(text="Delete", on_release=self.popup.open, size_hint_y=0.1)

        self.add_widget(self.fichoo)
        self.add_widget(btn_delete)

    def delete(self, *args):
        os.remove(self.fichoo.selection[0])
        self.fichoo._update_files()


class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank You! Your answer is very, very useful. I implemented your advices in my code. I have motto for this: One my question, two your advices and a lot of my questions. . .On Stack Overflow I had question to Popip menu:Using Kivy Popup. Answer there and you obtain next vote.